# Sinc hyperbolic function in Python

Tags: python, trigonometry, hyperbolic-function

I am sure you have all heard of the sinc function defined as sinc(x) = sin(x)/x. There is an implementation in numpy which works great, but I was wondering if there was also a hyperbolic version of this function, i.e.

sinhc(x) = sinh(x)/x

Comment: I guess you could just _make_ this function: `sinhc = lambda x: sinh(x)/x`

Comment: There is still a divergence at x=0